# how to detect that app connected to local wifi

Tags: android, wifi

I have two buttons in my app one will be on for local wifi(specially for "ati"), other will be on for if connection is specific server is available like www.google.com
Please help that how can detect the app is connected to local wifi and also how can detect that connection is available to specific server , same behavior as of Reachability in IOS programming

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class to get the state of Wi-Fi. I think only way to check whether connection to specific server is available to actually connect.